# Regular Expression of Language {a b} which contains string of Odd Length and must contain atleast one 'b' in it

Tags: regex, automata

I've tried the following solution but it may not cover all the strings

b(aa+ab+ba+bb)* + (aa+ab+ba+bb)*b

here + means OR operation and * means repetition.

Can someone debug the above regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE = (a+b)((a+b)(a+b))`*`b(a+b)((a+b)(a+b))`*` `+`
((a+b)(a+b))`*`b((a+b)(a+b))`*`

I hope it will cover all strings

Answer (score 0):

check out this ..

```
b((a+b)(a+b))*
```

this results in generating strings with minimum length 1 i-e 
odd as per your requirement also containing (b);if you take closure once

for more than 1 odd lengths take closure multiple times

Comment: but it'll fail if the string starts with a